# ActiveRecordRelation where method matching on unique id returning object slightly diff then when traversing the array and matching on the same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

Pretty new to ruby, rails and unit testing so any additional feedback welcome!

I'm writing an rspec unit test for an ActiveRecord based model (contact) called #assign_campaign. ContactCampaign is an association mapping Contacts to Campaigns. The idea here is that when a campaign gets assigned all other campaigns for that contact get deactivated and the assigned campaign gets activated.

The test failed because it claims that status for the assigned campaign is nil and not 'active' (Or 'inactive').

What it seems to come down to is that "where" matching on the campaign_id attribute doesn't seem to return the same object as if I iterate through contact_campaigns and match also on campaign_id.

**E.g.**

```
contact.contact_campaigns.where(campaign_id: campaign_to_be_assigned.id).first.inspect
```

**Gets me:**

<ContactCampaign id: 6, contact_id: 1, campaign_id: 1, status: nil, created_at: "2013-09-11 23:40:07", updated_at: "2013-09-11 23:40:07", current_position: 1>

With an object_id of: 70199917191760

**While**

```
contact.contact_campaigns.each do |x|
  if x.campaign_id == campaign_to_be_assigned.id
    puts x.inspect
  end
end
```

**Gets me:**

<ContactCampaign id: 6, contact_id: 1, campaign_id: 1, status: "active", created_at: "2013-09-11 23:40:07", updated_at: "2013-09-11 23:40:08", current_position: 1>

With an object_id of: 70199940110940

What is going on here? Is this an ActiveRecord fail, a FactoryGirl fail or simple Ruby fail? ;p

If I rewrite assign_campaign from:

```
current_contact_campaign = contact_campaigns.where(campaign_id: campaign_id).first
current_contact_campaign.activate
current_contact_campaign.set_current_position(starting_position) unless
  starting_position == 0
```

To:

```
contact_campaigns.each do |x|
  if x.campaign_id == campaign_id
    x.activate
    x.set_current_position(starting_position) unless
      starting_position == 0
  end
end
```

Then everything is happy, but I want to know what's going on.

**Rspec Test:**

```
it "assign_campaign assigns a campaign, creates a new campaign task,
    note and deactivates other contact campaigns, one was active previously" do
  # not checking the note portion right now

  contact = FactoryGirl.create(:contact, user: user)
  campaign_to_be_assigned = FactoryGirl.create(:campaign)
  campaign_to_be_assigned.messages << FactoryGirl.create(:message)

  5.times do |i|
    contact.campaigns << FactoryGirl.create(:campaign)
  end
  contact.deactivate_contact_campaigns

  # Randomly activates one of the generated campaigns
  contact.contact_campaigns[rand(4)].activate

  contact.assign_campaign(campaign_to_be_assigned.id)

  contact.contact_campaigns.each do |x|
    if x.campaign_id == campaign_to_be_assigned.id
      x.status.should == 'active'
    else
      x.status.should == 'inactive'
    end
  end
end
```

**Method being tested:**

```
def assign_campaign(campaign_id=nil, starting_position = 0,  opts = {})
  if email_is_valid || campaign_id == nil
    if !campaign_id.blank?
      campaign = Campaign.find(campaign_id)
      deactivate_contact_campaigns
      campaigns << campaign if !campaigns.include? campaign
      current_contact_campaign = contact_campaigns.where(campaign_id: campaign_id).first
      current_contact_campaign.activate
      current_contact_campaign.set_current_position(starting_position) unless
        starting_position == 0
      notes.create(user_id: user.id, body: "Assigned #{name} to " +
        campaign.description, group: "system",
        created_at: (opts[:assign_time] ? opts[:assign_time] : Time.now))
      create_new_campaign_task(opts[:user_id],
        (starting_position == 0 ? 0 : (starting_position - 1)))
      return true
    else
      notes.create(user_id: user.id,
        body: "Unassigned #{name} from campaign", group: "system",
        created_at: (opts[:assign_time] ? opts[:assign_time] : Time.now)) if
          contact_campaigns.where(status: 'active').size > 0
      deactivate_contact_campaigns        
    end
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

**Test Fail Message**

```
Failures:

  1) Contact assign_campaign assigns a campaign, creates a new campaign task,
      note and deactivates other contact campaigns, one was active previously
     Failure/Error: x.status.should == 'active'
       expected: "active"
            got: nil (using ==)
     # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:78:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/contact_spec.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**FactoryGirl Factories**

campaigns

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :campaign do |campaign|
    sequence(:description) { |n| "description#{n}"}
  end
end
```

contacts

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do  
  factory :contact do |contact|
    fake_email = Faker::Internet.email
    association :organization, factory: :organization
    sequence(:email) { |n| "#{n}#{fake_email}" }
  end
end
```

messages

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :message do |message|
      message.description { "Considering buying your first home?" }
      message.position { 0 }
      message.interval { 0 }
      message.email_subject { "Considering buying your first home?" }
      message.email_body { "I have several valuable resources if you are considering buying your first home. I'm happy to discuss the process of buying a home in simple, easy-to-understand terms, or I can help point you in the right direction to get the best loan for a home purchase.\n\nIf you're just curious what you can get for your money, I'm happy to show you a few properties in your area so you can see what is available. Give me a call today anytime. I look forward to hearing from you." }
  end
end
```

Comment: Try executing the same where statement twice. You will get different object_ids. Thats how object_ids work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding your first question about object_ids:**

The object_id is an internal reference id in Ruby assigned to the actual instance. No two instances can have the same object_id. This is different from calling .id in Rails which should return the id of the record in your datastore.

**Why your test is probably failing:** 
The moment you called this:

```
contact.contact_campaigns[rand(4)].activate
```

Rails hit your datastore and cached the collection locally. Then you "activated" the item rand(4), which clearly appears to be your intention.

Then you called this:

```
contact.assign_campaign(campaign_to_be_assigned.id)
```

which should have deactivated the previously active rand(4). But, in the datastore **NOT** in memory in contact.contact_campaigns. So remember contact.contact_campaigns is still in memory and thinks that rand(4) is activated. So before you do this:

```
contact.contact_campaigns.each do...
```

You should reload the collection:

```
contact.contact_campaigns.reload
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's an impressive answer for someone with a reputation of 1. :-) Did you just decide to start getting active on SO?

Comment: Wow.. that's really informative :) Sorry I didn't read sooner had email alerts set. I'll fiddle around and see if it fixes things to see if there's a resolution. Thanks masahji for the great reply!

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Yeah I thought it would be a better use of my time than watching clips of old NBA basketball games.

Comment: Yup that did the trick! Thanks so much masahji. Yeah in memory vs in the datastore somehow eluded me completely. Was operating under the impression Ruby's magic extended to memory/datastore one-ness ;p

Comment: @masahji, great answer! What is it about this case that necessitates a reload call? Why wouldnt contact.assign_campaign make the change in memory as well?